# how to plot a Live graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using SimpleCV and Camera device i am generating data in the given form using "while loop" after capturing  video for 10 second :

1    12.00000
2    12.56578
3    14.56500
4    13.45456
5    11.45667

now how can i plot this data in real time please help

Comment: @jsalonen actually my problem is that i am not able to feed the given data to the plot in real time, i am not able to write code properly. All the examples available just using randomly generated data by code itself but i want to use data which is generate by first code and used in real time plotting .

Comment: If you feel like the linked issue doesn't solve your problem, please clarify your question. A suggested format is: 1) the problem you encounter, 2) example input, 3) the result you want to get and 4) what you have tried so far. Thanks!